# how to send notify_url from script for paypal recurring payment.

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

i am using this script. https://www.paypal-brasil.com.br/desenvolvedores/code-sample/recurring-payments-php/

Is this possible to get notification using IPN on each PayPal call for recurring using notify url. When using setExpressCheckOut. i want to use script to set notify_url for this job.

I can't save notification url in PayPal setting. Because i am using 5 websites with one PayPal Account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recurring Payments IPNs only work from the IPN configuration in the PayPal account.  NotifyURL will not work with recurring payments.

Comment: Ok thanks. 
I can't save notification url in PayPal setting. Because i am using 5 websites with one PayPal Account

Comment: Is there any other way to run IPN ??

Comment: You could setup an IPN forwarder.  Then set your PayPal accounts to all point to that IPN URL, and from there you can forward the data to unique IPN URLs depending on details in that transaction data.

Comment: Hi, sorry did not get. Can you give me a example how can i do this ?